# Best way to display tabular financial summary data in ios

Tags: ios

I want to display financial summary data in an ios app e.g.

Total Price   123
Tax            10
Shipping        5
Total         138

I want this data to look like a table e.g. with different formatting treatment for different rows e.g. different font/background. Also I want to hide certain row like tax if it is no applicable, without leaving a gap behind.

Right now I am doing this by displaying a view for each row, and using autolayout constraints to define vertical spacing between the views. If I need to hide the the view for tax if its not applicable then I hide the view and also have to change vertical spacing constraint to remove a gap.

This seems overcomplicated so I am considering alternatives like

- using uitableview - seems also heavy handed since all display is read only
- using uiwebview to render server generated html - seems like an option but I already have all data I need, so dont want to hit server
- using uiwebview and generating html in app - not sure how easy this is to do?
- using uitextview with nsattributedstring - seems cumbersome
- using uitextview with nsattributedstring with html add-ons using 3rd party library - could be best option

interested in what people think is a good solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> using uitableview - seems also heavy handed since all display is read only

Table views are often used for read only data. This solution should offer you a very fast and easy solution

> using uiwebview to render server generated html - seems like an option but I already have all data I need, so dont want to hit server

You could generate the HTML on the device, it isn't a complex procedure when you have a static format

> using uiwebview and generating html in app - not sure how easy this is to do?

As above, but web view is going to add a little lag however you use it

> using uitextview with nsattributedstring - seems cumbersome

A little, perhaps. It depends very much on what your layout format it.

> using uitextview with nsattributedstring with html add-ons using 3rd party library - could be best option

Similar to using a text view. If using a library it would usually offer you a different view. If you want tables you should use a web view.

Overall, start with the table view if you want a list of items, particularly if the format of each cell is the same.

Comment: One issue I have with using a table view is that I want the financial summary view to take up a different height in the screen depending on how many rows are returned, not sure how easy this will to be do using table view, maybe easier to just add the views for each row to a parent view programatically?

Comment: You mean you don't want the table to scroll? You can make it less than full screen. Either use a view controller with a table view subview or a child table view controller.

Comment: I used the table view and it worked great, much simpler than laying out elements individually, thanks